# Write in the ASSETS folder

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I would like to WRITE to my HTML file in the ASSETS folder.

Please note because my HTML is related to other FILES/FOLDERS i cannot use the personal folder. I must write at the

Assets/HTML/mycharts.html

```
[MY WRITING code below return these errors

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("file:///android_asset/myGraphs/BarGraph.html", s);

]
```

ERRORS

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "//file:///android_asset/myGraphs/BarGraph.html".
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,bool,System.IO.FileOptions) <0x00208>
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare) <0x00057>
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (string,bool,System.Text.Encoding,int) <0x00087>
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (string,bool,System.Text.Encoding) <0x00037>
at


]
```

Comment: the best approach I can think of is to stream copy from your assets to your files and reference to your html in your files not in your assets.

Comment: Correct am ABLE to stream from the ASSETS. BUT more IMPORTANTLY I want to UPDATE my ASSETS DYNAMICALLY at Runtime from time to time? By the way can we host HTML files elsewhere APart from (ASSETS/CONTENT/MYHTMLFILE.html) and acess them with WEBVIEW?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write to the assets folder or edit any files in there. It is read-only.

**EDIT:**
As suggested in the comments is to initially have your HTML in your assets and when needed they will be saved either on the SD card or in the private storage.

For storing files on SD card you can get the path to the SD card like so:

```
var folder = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + Java.IO.File.Separator + "MyAppFolder";
```

`"MyAppFolder"` can be anything you want it to be, as long as it does not clash with some of the other folder names on the SD card, so make sure to check if it exists already. Combine that with a file name like so:

```
var extFileName = folder + Java.IO.File.Separator + "MyFile.txt";
```

Now write something to the file:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
using (var fs = new FileStream(extFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    var buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello, world!");
    fs.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
}
```

If you want to store data in the internal storage you can get the path to the private storage with:

```
var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Comment: yeah I agree. It seems you only store items at ASSETS at design time and access them. You may not write to ASSETS at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this based off the above solution with this code:

```
               using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( this.contextCalledFrom.Assets.Open("pdfreport.html")))
           html = sr.ReadToEnd();

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            client.convertHtml(html, memoryStream);

            var folder = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + Java.IO.File.Separator + "wpfolder";

            if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

            var extFileName = folder + Java.IO.File.Separator + "report.pdf";

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(extFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
           {
               memoryStream.WriteTo(file);
           }
```